# presenting a modal view controller without storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a custom UIWebView to present a login page. I am able to get this to show by adding it as a subview. But I would like to present this modally and programatically without the use of a storyboard!

Answer (score 1):

Put it in an otherwise empty view controller, and then call

```
[self presentViewController: animated: completion:]
```

in the view controller you're wanting to present it from. When you're done, you can call

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated: completion:]
```

to get rid of it again. This message can be sent to either the presenter or the presented view controller, though in either case it ultimately is the presenter which responds.

Comment: Hi Josh, just to note that you can actually send the second message to the *presented* controller itself and it will forward it automatically to the presenter. So, no need for an unwind segue.